# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in discord and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, giphy-api

this is the error

```
let token = msg.content.split(' ');
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Client.msg (/app/bot.js:15:27)
    at Client.emit (events.js:196:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/rbd/pnpm-volume/3c4dae99-ae7d-482d-8189-d37183b015d2/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/rbd/pnpm-volume/3c4dae99-ae7d-482d-8189-d37183b015d2/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/3c4dae99-ae7d-482d-8189-d37183b015d2/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/3c4dae99-ae7d-482d-8189-d37183b015d2/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/3c4dae99-ae7d-482d-8189-d37183b015d2/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/3c4dae99-ae7d-482d-8189-d37183b015d2/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/ws/7.4.2/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:196:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/3c4dae99-ae7d-482d-8189-d37183b015d2/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/ws/7.4.2/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:825:20)
```

this is the code

```
console.log("loding");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login(process.env.SECRET);

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on("message", msg);

    function msg() {
```

this line gives error

let token = msg.content.split(' ');

```
  if ((msg.channel.id = "791583092275937303")) {
    if (token[0] === "ping") {
      msg.reply("Pong!");
    } else if (token[0] === "!gif") {
      msg.reply("ok wait");
```

i have blanked it out

```
      let APIKEY = "**************";
      let limit = "100";
      let search= 'ok';
      let rating = 'g'
      if (token.length > 1){
        search.slice(1,search.length).join(" ");
      }
      
      const gifForm = document.querySelector("#gif-form");
      gifForm.addEventListener("submit", fetchGiphs);

      function fetchGiphs(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
```

this fetches giphy gif

```
        fetch(
          `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?&q=${search}&limit=${limit}&api_key=${APIKEY}&rating=${rating}`
        )
          .then(response => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(resp => {
```

// Here we get the data array from the response object

```
let dataArray = resp.data;
            console.log(dataArray);
            msg.channel.send()
})
```

// We pass the array to showGiphs function

// We use catch method for Error handling

```
 .catch(err => console.log(err)); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If the erorr is saying "cannot read property `anyProperty` of undefined" then that means that the value which you're asking for a property of is undefined. So in this case `Array.split()` is defined, but the value you're calling it on is either `null`, `undefined`, or not an array. Hope this helps!

Comment: no it says that the split can't be done

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined" basically means that "The value that `.split()` was called on does not have a `.split()` method" I didn't read your code, but unless you're trying to run a method which isn't `Array.split` then this should be accurate. The type error that you put in the title suggests that my thinking is correct, but maybe you put in the wrong title and it has nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to call `split` on `undefined`.

Don't do that.

First, check to see if it exists.

```
let token;
if (msg && msg.content) {
  token = msg.content.split(" ");
}
```

Or use the newer optional chaining.

```
let token = msg?.content?.split(' ');
```